# DOMDocument C++ memory management

Tags: c++, xml, memory-management, domdocument, xerces-c

Question about DOM* class createXXX methods in C++.  Do I have to do anything special to free memory returned from DOM* createXXX methods?

For example (the transcodes were removed for simplification and the associated releases for the vars associated with the transcode operations, I know about those):

```
pImplement = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation("LS");
DOMDocument* pDoc = pImplement->createDocument("Examples", "example", NULL );
DOMElement* pRoot = pDoc->getDocumentElement();

DOMElement* firstElement = pDoc->createElementNS(("Examples", "example");
DOMElement* secondElement = pDoc->createElementNS("Examples", "example2");

DOMAttr* name = pDoc->createAttribute("Name");

XMLCh* somenameValue = XMLString::transcode("Fred");
name->setValue(somenameValue);

secondElement->setAttributeNode(name);
firstElement->appendChild(secondElement);
```

When I leave the method eventually, do I have to do anything special for firstElement, secondElement, name to free the memory from the createXXX methods?  Or does pdoc own all the memory and I have to wait to destroy the DOMDocument?

If adds to the discussion, I loop over the name/value logic and add multiple attributes to the secondElement.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From memory of my experience using DOM classes, you don't have to delete anything that you append to the DOM tree. For example, you append the child `secondElement` to the element `firstElement`. When the latter gets freed, it will also free `secondElement`. However, I see two things here that will leak. First, you don't insert `firstElement` into the DOM tree, and second, you don't explicitly delete `pDoc` when you leave. You have to either free the element or add it to the DOM tree and delete it at some point latter in your code.

Comment: thanks.  That what I thought but we are seeing some mem issues with Xerces/Xalan and I wanted to double check.

Answer (score 1):

Note: by the name of the functions involved I'll assume you're talking about Xerces-C.

You only need to call [release](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMNode.html#69b331aca0adcd37a41efa9492c0c9cf) on the root of the tree (be it an DOMElement (to delete just a "branch' of the tree) or a DOMDocument (to delete the entire tree)).
So, adding a call to `pDoc->release();` at the end will take care of freeing the memory of the document and all nodes **attached** to that document.